# Empty title on one View based on Taxonomy Terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm struggling with a couple of pages that won't propagate a page title.  Because the view is based on Taxonomy Terms I want it to change the page title to the taxonomy term it's using. I've spent hours going through different drupal blogs etc to try and trouble shoot the problem but nothing's working.  The site is www.skyviewelectronics.com and the problem pages are all the pages that use the collection Taxonomy Terms:
/collection/cables-and-connectors
/collection/cell-phone-signal-boosters
/collection/clearance
/collection/computer-software
/collection/computers
/collection/data-storage-and-backup-drives
/collection/hd-tv-antenna-accessories
/collection/hd-tv-antennas
/collection/high-speed-internet
/collection/networking
/collection/notebook-bags
/collection/protection-and-cleaning
/collection/security

I've turned off the Metatag View module since some people report that is a problem.
Here is the options for my view:

[image: View Taxonomy term]

Here is the options I have for the contextual Filter under content: has taxonomy term ID (with depth)  - I've also tried without depth, and many many many other combos...

[image: Contextual Filter: Has taxonomy term ID (With Depth) - override Title]

Can anyone help??

Comment: have you tried removing the first contextual filter 'Content: Collection'?

Comment: Hi Jason - If I remove the "content: collection" it will remove the association with the taxonomy terms I need it to pull from.  "collection" is a taxonomy Vocabulary...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer (might not be the right answer but it's working).  I changed the "title" section in the View to %1 %2 and it started pulling from the metatag title section in each taxonomy term.